# PyQt4 QTextEdit: Vertical text in the HTML table

Tags: html, python-2.7, pyqt4

I found example in PyQt4/examples/demos called Textedit, that creates documents from HTML file, and I'm using it for table reports like MS Access reports. Everything works fine, but I can't set text in HTML tables vertically. I'm trying that code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>QTextEdit Demonstration</title>

<style type="text/css">
p.vertical{
writing-mode:tb-rl;
filter:flipH flipV;
height:60px;
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="99%">
<tr>
<td><p class = "vertical"><span>vertical</span></p></td>
<td><p><span>horizontal</span></p></td>
<td><p><span>0</span></p></td></tr>
</table></body></html>
```

In browser it works fine, but when I'm opening it in Textedit, it doesn't. Is there another way to set text vertically in TextEdit?

Comment: There is no way to do this using QTextEdit, or any other class that uses Qt's own [rich-text (html) rendering engine](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html). It only supports a limited subset of HTML4/CSS2. If you really want this, you will have to dynamically create images of the vertical text. The only other solution would be to use a heavyweight browser class like QWebEngineView.

Comment: Thanks for help, @ekhumoro, I'll use PIL for images.

Answer (score 0):

QTextEdit only supports a subset of attributes, see here for those supported:

```
http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html
```

I would recommend QTextDocument with  defaultStyleSheet property:

```
http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtextdocument.html#defaultStyleSheet-prop
```

Comment: QTextEdit uses a QTextDocument, so this is no help at all.